# Add custom data with order email content magento

Tags: email, magento

Suppose I have a variable like $something ="xyz_xyz". I want to add/concatenate this variable with the order email content in magento.  So that, customer can see  my variable output in email.

I have searched in google but can't understand the solution.How can i do this?

**Here $something is actually dynamic variable.**
Please make me suggest also the file, file path and method which generates the order email .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open file located at [magento]\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php

locate function **public function sendNewOrderEmail()**

find

```
$something ="xyz_xyz";
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $this,
                'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
                'custom'       => $something //your custom value here
            )
        );
```

locate file `[magento]\app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new.html`

you can access your variable

```
{{var custom}}
```

hope this help you

**Note: Don't change in core files instead override it**